# Add components to GridLayout starting from the last component?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm writing a small board game program, and there's a small hiccup that's preventing me from progressing: The game board is composed of 4 grid layouts (one for each side of the board, top and bottom sides are 7 columns, 1 row and left and right side are 1 column, 5 rows). I'm tracking the position of each tile in an ArrayList (index 0 represents the top-left tile and then each tile number increases in a clockwise fashion).

The problem is this: When it gets to the bottom side of the board, in order to preserve the clockwise movement order, the tiles (components of the bottom grid layout) should be added starting from the last element to the first whereas now, they're (logically) added at the beginning of the grid layout so the indexes in the ArrayList become mixed up for the bottom rom and the left column of the board.

I'm looking for a way to do this efficiently (the methods I thought of so far are messy and complicated). So how could I get a GridLayout that starts adding components from the last element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how could I get a GridLayout that starts adding components from the last element?

```
panel.add(component, 0);
```

This will add the component to the beginning of panel shifting all the other components down.

Comment: Oh wow, that's amazing! Thank you very much. So in other words, if add a 2nd element, the first I've added will be in the second cell and the newest element will be first?

Comment: I literally just added the `0` argument and now everything works perfectly, thanks a lot!